# Cannot dynamically allocate a matrix in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I want to make a function that reads the first two integers of a .txt file as the number of rows and columns of a dynamically allocated matrix and then print the matrix.
Here's how i thought it would work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *openFileR(const char *);
int rows(FILE *);
int cols(FILE *);
void printMat(int **, int, int);


int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=openFileR("matrix.txt");
    int nrows=rows(fp); int ncols=cols(fp);
    printf("Rows:%d\nColumns:%d\n", nrows, ncols);
    int **matrix;
    matrix=malloc(nrows*(sizeof(int *)));
    for(int i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i]=malloc(ncols*sizeof(int));
    }

    printMat(matrix, nrows, ncols);
    return 0;
}



void printMat(int **matrix, int nrows, int ncols)
{
    for(int i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<ncols; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int cols(FILE *fp)
{
    int columns;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &columns);
    return columns;
}

int rows(FILE *fp)
{
    int lines;
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &lines);
    return lines;
}

FILE *openFileR(const char *nome_file)
{
    FILE *fp;
    printf("File name: %s\n", nome_file);
    fp=fopen(nome_file, "r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    printf("File correctly opened\n");
    return fp;
}
```

The problem is that the output i get from `printMat` function is just a one-dimensional array of 5 elements (the `ncols`  value) instead of a matrix.
I think there's a problem with the matrix allocation but i don't get what it is.

matrix.txt=
`4 5`

Comment: You did not initialize any of the `matrix[i][j]` values, what do you expect it to print?

Comment: @Simone Parente There is a typo in the third expression  for(int j=0; j<ncols; i++) There must be j++

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, thank you very much, i feel so stupid now

Comment: I see where you read the `rows` and `cols` values.  Where do you read the rest of the values?

Comment: Error messages should be written to stderr, and they should be informative: `if(fp==NULL){ perror(nome_file); ...`